# How to calculate the Overall Elapse Time of the SLA?

Tags: apex, casemilestone

I am working on the OOTB `Milestones` and now looking to calculate the Sum of the Elapse Time.

1. How we can calculate the sum of all these Elapse Times using formula fields? Do I need to write some other logic ? As we all know we can not edit/update the CaseMilestones fields.
2. In some cases, I only need to get the overall(End-to-End SLA) Elapse Time. So in this, I have to used Category & sub category value to differentiate from the another SLA's. How can I only get the 1st SLA elapse time ? Do I need to show Total Elapse time when all milestones are completed, right ?

[image]

**How we can get the Elaspse Time of all Milestone attached to that case using SOQL ?** Any guidance around this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this upon executing following SOQL

```
SELECT SUM(ElapsedTimeInMins) 
From CaseMilestone 
WHERE CaseId = '<case id>' 
and IsCompleted = true
```

Refer [CaseMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_casemilestone.htm) Object definition

**Update**

You could limit your query to display the first record milestone record. You could also add case attributes (Category and Sub Category) in the filter.

```
SELECT CaseId, Case.Category__c,
    CompletionDate,
    CreatedDate,
    ElapsedTimeInMins,Id,
    IsCompleted,
    IsDeleted,
    IsViolated,
    MilestoneTypeId,
    MilestoneType.Name, 
    StartDate 
FROM CaseMilestone  
WHERE CaseId='<case id>' AND IsCompleted=true 
AND Case.Category__c = '<my category>' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: The context of SLA handling is not clear from the question

Comment: find my updated answer to get the 1st SLA

Comment: Thanks, My Category & SubCategory is on the Case Object. How we can get that at the CaseMilestone query ?

Comment: sure !, please upvote the question too !

Comment: In this case, how I will come to know which milestone was trigger 1st out of three ?

Comment: you can put Order BY CreatedDate, so the first one you will get