# Calculate the Total ElapsTime of each milestone on case

Tags: apex, trigger, entitlements

I am working on the `Entitlement Process` and `Milestones`. When the case is `closed`, I need to calculate `Total ElaspseTime` of all the milestones. I've taken a reference from link : [How to calculate the Overall Elapse Time of the SLA?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/187758/how-to-calculate-the-overall-elapse-time-of-the-sla) .

Then for sure I need to write logic in after update Trigger.

I have written the below logic and needs some modification, also looking to bulkyfy the code. When Case is closed, Total ElaseTime of each Case should be calculated.

```
public static void calculateElasTime(List<Id> caseIds, String category, String subCategory){

        Map<Id, CaseMilestone> cmsMap = new Map<Id, CaseMilestone>([SELECT CaseId, Case.Category__c,
                                        CompletionDate,
                                        ElapsedTimeInMins,
                                        IsCompleted,
                                        MilestoneTypeId,
                                        MilestoneType.Name, 
                                        StartDate,Case.IsClosed 
                                    FROM CaseMilestone  
                                    WHERE CaseId IN ('LLLLLL','KKKKKK') 
                                    AND IsCompleted=true AND Case.IsClosed=true
                                    AND Case.Category__c ='Paypal'
                                    AND Case.SubCategory__c IN ('Basic Auth','Ssale')]);

        Map<Id, List<CaseMilestone>> caseIdToMilestone = new Map<Id, List<CaseMilestone>>();
        for(Id mId : cmsMap.keySet()){
            if(caseIdToMilestone.containsKey(cmsMap.get(mId).CaseId)){
                caseIdToMilestone.get(cmsMap.get(mId).CaseId).add(cmsMap.get(mId));
            }
            else{
                List<CaseMilestone> casesList = new List<CaseMilestone>();
                casesList.add(cmsMap.get(mId));
                caseIdToMilestone.put(cmsMap.get(mId).CaseId, casesList);
            }
        }

        Map<Id, Integer> caseIdToElapseTime = new Map<Id, Integer>();
        for(Id cid : caseIdToMilestone.keySet()){
            List<CaseMilestone> mtList = caseIdToMilestone.get(cid);
            Integer sum = 0;
            for(CaseMilestone cm : mtList){
                sum += cm.ElapsedTimeInMins;
                caseIdToElapseTime.put(cid, sum);
            }
        }       
    }
```

**I think, in the Trigger.New we should check isClosed=True, instead of making call to database to check case is closed ?** I am facing in updating the result and bulkifying the code.

EDIT:-1

```
I am getting very wired error:
Error: Invalid Data. 
    Review all error messages below to correct your data.
    Apex trigger CaseTrigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: CaseTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 500c0000009ggifAAA; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CaseTrigger: maximum trigger depth exceeded Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif] Case trigger event AfterUpdate for [500c0000009ggif]: []: Class.CalculateElapseTimeUtil.calculateAllElapseTime: line 33, column 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to calculate `Total ElaspseTime` of all the milestones for each Case.

Here it is using `Aggregate query` which is most efficient for this purpose:

```
public static void calculateElasTime(List<Id> caseIds, String category, String subCategory)
{
    List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();

    List<AggregateResult> results = [SELECT CaseId, SUM(ElapsedTimeInMins) elpsTime
                                    FROM CaseMilestone  
                                    WHERE CaseId IN:caseIds 
                                    AND IsCompleted=true AND Case.IsClosed=true
                                    AND Case.Category__c ='Paypal'
                                    AND Case.SubCategory__c IN ('Basic Auth','Ssale')
                                    GROUP BY CaseId]);

    for(AggregateResult result:results)
    {
        Case caseObj = new Case (Id = (Id) result.get('CaseId'), Total_ElapseTime__c = (Integer) result.get('elpsTime'));
        lstCase.add(caseObj);
    }
    update lstCase;
}
```

**Update based on comments**

You need to perform this operation in `after trigger`. Since record is readonly in after trigger context, you have a create a new instance of case object, prepare a list and finally update.

Comment: yes thanks !, for some category and subCategory I only want to calculate 1st Milestones elapseTime and from that perspective please provide the solution. Also provide solution for how to show data in Number Field Named as Total_ElapseTime__C

Comment: Thats not your original question. you can ask a separate question upon accepting this

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: basically, follow the best practice whatever code is

Comment: you can do the conversion well, just google some sample code and fit into that conversion

Comment: I tried I am getting weird error. New question created here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188552/cannot-insert-update-activate-entity-casetrigger-maximum-trigger-depth-exceede